# Component to display multiline text in Delphi

Tags: delphi, text, components

I'm a Delphi programmer and I'm trying to write an application in which I want to show text from a telnet server.
For inputting the commands to send I'm using a TLabeledEdit and for receiving the data I'm using TIdTelnet. That works without any problems so far.
But which component should I use to display the text so the output looks like the console window?
Should I use a multiline TLabel and place it into a TScrollBox or a TMemo with TabStop property set to False or is there a better solution?

Comment: Use a memo with a mono-spaced font to emulate a terminal window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use a TMemo (or its alternative, TRichEdit).

Comment: There's something else actually crossed my mind: Is it right that TMemo and TRichEdit have only a finite capacity? So if I use this component then I have to check the text length before adding everytime I received the telnet data, is this correct?

Comment: Both TMemo and TRichEdit have a finite capacity as you say.
The later, TRichEdit has a much higher capacity (2GB), so I would suggest using it instead of a TMemo.

Comment: You can dynamically set the capacity of both controls at runtime.

Comment: @altralaser: In older Delphi versions, TMemo indeed had a limited capacity, but I think that was somewhere in the D2 - D4 era. After that, it may be limited by default, but it can be changed to use the full 2GB.

Comment: @Rudy: Yes, the limit was 64kB.

Comment: @SkyFlyer: it ***was*** 64KB, indeed. But only in the oldest versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a TListBox if wish to add additional functionality like painting the background of certain lines of text.

Comment: You can do that with a TRichEdit as well via the `EM_SETCHARFORMAT` message and `CHARFORMAT2` struct.

Comment: @Remy: Indeed, TRIchEdit would be a better choice for this.